# How can i slideUp() part of a form before i display it to the user?

Tags: jquery

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayd360/NsvD5/2)

I have multiple fieldsets and the user can also choose to create fieldsets. When the user focuses on the 'question' input the 'answer' input fields slides down (if its not already down) and all other 'answer' fields slide up.

At the first part of the program it automatically adds two forms that show the question and answer fields but i want to hide the second answer field to save room until they click the question input and it slides down.

Comment: this is fairly simple in jQuery. You should learn it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/GyFz3/

Contain the focus in the `document.ready`, then call `.trigger()` on the first field.

Comment: Thank you for the input and i like this answer but i am trying to hide or slideUp the answer fields before i show it to the user.

Comment: unfortunately no. I am hoping to somehow hide the answerfields *before* it is displayed to the user. I am unsure if it is possible in jQuery tho :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GyFz3/2/

This would just hide them instead of sliding... before they see it.

Answer (score -1):

add this

```
$(function(){
   var i = 0;
   $('li.answerFields').each(function(){
        if(i>0)
         $(this).hide()
       i++;
   });
 });
```

Comment: This will hide the first fieldset's answer block too. The OP only wants to hide the **second** answer field on page load.

Comment: when user focus on question input answer fields will slide down.

Comment: But the first answer block is supposed to be open when the page loads. Only the second should be hidden.

Comment: than simply add an counter to pass for the first item.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap the answer section in your second fieldset in a div with a classname (let's use `answer_wrapper`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('.second_fieldset').children('.answer_wrapper').hide();
});
```

This line will hide your second answer block.  To open it, add something like this to your call function:

```
$('.formheader').live('focus', function() {
   // Normal stuff
   $(this).siblings('.second_fieldset').show();
});
```